# NodeJS: Getting the changes in a file indefinitely

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, fs

I have a bash script that append a line of strings to a file indefinitely.

I'm trying to use **fs.readStream** to get the changes in the file and stream the newly appended lines back to users via websocket.

Basically, the idea is:

1. Bash script appends a string to a file (say, '/tmp/a.log') indefinitely.
2. node script would stream the file and read the last line everytime the file has been changed.
3. node would send the new lines via websocket.

But I have problems wrapping my head around **fs.readStream** and **fs.writeStream**.

Am I going with the right approach here? Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be a regular file? If you were to use a unix domain socket instead, it would be easier to listen for data on the node.js side (and also it would be more flexible because you could just switch it to a network socket instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [npm tail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tail) that implements fs.watch function and provides the manipulation of the newly inserted line.